# Can I used encrypted connections with Oracle Instant Client and ODP.NET?

Tags: c#, oracle, encryption, odp.net

We're currently using a fully installed oracle client and ado.net via odbc to establish an sql*net encrypted connection to an oracle database.

My question is if we can achieve encrypted connections with the instant client and odp.net instead of full client and odbc, too?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://kb.berkeley.edu/jivekb/entry.jspa?externalID=1005) seems to indicate that you can, though I've not tried it.

I think this will only work for native encryption, not with Advanced Security Option, which I believe requires the client install.